# How to get details of image template?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

From what I have seen through SoftLayer UI, after I create an image template and try using it to order a Virtual Server, the options are already selected to match the host that the image template was created.
So I am guessing the template would contain all the details on CPU, memory, disk space, and etc.  How do I get these details?

My guess is that "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group" represents the image template so it would have some API that tells me the details of the image template, but I haven't found the API that might give me that information unless I missed it..

Which API do I use to get the details of image template in SoftLayer?
(so that I know what value is selected for which category and etc.)

Comment: As an example, let say I have a Virtual Server with 1GB of RAM, 20 GB disk space, and Ubuntu OS.  And I created an image template from it.
When I try to order a virtual server using this image template, the virtual server options should be preset to 1GB of RAM, 20GB disk space, and Ubuntu OS.
And these configuration information must be stored some where like within the image template.
So what API(s) can I use which will tell me all the configuration information of the image template such as the
1GB of RAM, 20GB disk space, Ubuntu OS and etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

An image template contains information about OS and disk. You can get the details from an image template with the following method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getObject

To get information from the packages in which image could be used:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAvailablePackagesForImageTemplate

Also, the following method will help you to retrieve the items which could be applied to the image:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemsFromImageTemplate

I hope this information can help you

Comment: For the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::getObject(), it only gives very basic info about the template group.  I need information on all the configuration details.

Comment: I'm not sure if SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemsFromImageTemplate() would give me the info I want, but when it says it takes an SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group as parameter, how exactly do I pass this?  This is one of the SoftLayer APIs part that I hadn't figured out yet..  Could you perhaps give some examples of how I would actually invoke the SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemsFromImageTemplate() call?  Maybe examples in REST or PHP code?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following php script, it will help to get available packages and its items for an image template,

```
<?php
/**
 * Get packages and items from an image template
 *
 * This script retrieves packages in which the image template could be used, 
 * also It retrieves the items available for the image per package.
 *
 * Important manual pages:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAvailablePackagesForImageTemplate
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemsFromImageTemplate
 *
 * License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
 * Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/
require_once __DIR__."SoapClient.php";

# Your SoftLayer username and apikey
$username = "set me";
$apiKey = "set me";

# The image template which you wish more details
$imageTemplateId = 429428;
# Creating a SoftLayer API client object
$packageService = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient("SoftLayer_Product_Package", null, $username, $apiKey);

/*
 * Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group object to define the image template id 
 */
$imageTemplate = new \stdClass();
$imageTemplate -> id = $imageTemplateId;

try {
    // Get available packages for the image template
    $packages = $packageService -> getAvailablePackagesForImageTemplate($imageTemplate);
    foreach ($packages as $package)
    {
        // Set init parameters per available package 
        $packageService -> setInitParameter($package->id);
        // Print available package
        print_r("**** PACKAGE: " . $package->id . " ****\n");
        // Get items per package
        $items = $packageService -> getItemsFromImageTemplate($imageTemplate);
        print_r($items);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Unable to get packages and items for the image template. " . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

References:
SoftLayer API PHP client: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-api-php-client

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a shot. But I have to resolve some other issue before I can get to this, so it may be a few days before I can try this.